# Why would running LocateFeautresAlongRoutes GP tool return null?

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, .net, arcgis-9.3, linear-referencing

I'm currently using the `LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes` tool wrapper for C#/.NET for a custom tool I'm developing for ArcMap 9.3.1.  I've been able to run this tool in ArcMap outside of code in a tool with the same files as parameters.

Unfortunately when I put it in code I keep getting null for the `IGeoProcessorResult`.  Is there any reason why I would get a null object for the result instead of just saying it failed? Also, is there anything wrong with the below code?

The relevant block of code is below.

```
LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes lfar = new LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes();
lfar.in_features = @"C:\GIS_Temp\CONGPROP.mdb\CONGPROP2";
lfar.in_routes = @"C:\GIS_Temp\Routes.mdb\routes";
lfar.route_id_field = "ROUTE_ID";
lfar.out_table = "eventTable.dbf";
lfar.out_event_properties = "ROUTE_ID LINE FMEAS TMEAS";
lfar.in_fields = "NO_FIELDS";

Geoprocessor geoprocessor = new Geoprocessor();
geoprocessor.TemporaryMapLayers = false;
geoprocessor.OverwriteOutput = true;
geoprocessor.AddOutputsToMap = true;
IGeoProcessorResult result = (IGeoProcessorResult) geoprocessor.Execute(lfar, null);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the `result` will return null if any of the inputs to the tool are not correct. I found the best way when you don't know all of the parameters is to get the Python script from a run of the tool that *was* successful. This will at least get how the parameters should look, and that can be converted to .NET.

Comment: Still getting used to this... I guess I didn't have enough confidence to say I answered my own question :)